# Get selenium driver for each browser in parallel

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking for a way to run multiple browser capabilities in parallel on a cloud testing provider. The tests are written in python. I think I am most of the way there, but I am having trouble getting the driver for each browser to `tearDown`. The project will house tests for multiple sites and run against multiple platforms, browsers, browsers version and screen sizes. Right now I have a concept of most repeatable steps will be housed at the top level of the project and all the child directories (i.e. individual sites) will just import in the global modules. Right now this is just the setting up of the multiple browsers. That way I can just keep each child directory to just the tests themselves. Here is a very stripped down example of what I have.

The project structure would look something like

```
├── initializer.py
└── sites
    ├── site1
    │   ├── test1.py
    │   ├── test2.py
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   ├── setup.py
    │   └── test.py
    └── site2
        ├── test1.py
        ├── test2.py
        ├── requirements.txt
        ├── setup.py
        └── test.py
```

This will be the top level one that sets everything up and gets imported to child directories/sites `initializer.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import unittest
from threading import Thread
from selenium import webdriver
from desired_capabilities import *

API_EMAIL = os.environ["CBT_EMAIL"]
API_AUTH = os.environ["CBT_AUTH"]

class Setup(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        self.browsers = []
        self.browsers_waiting = []
        self.threads = []

    def setUp(self):
        for platform in platforms:
            # win
            if platform == "Windows 10":
                for version in win_10_chrome_versions:
                    self.gen_browser("Chrome", version, platform)
                for version in win_10_ff_versions:
                    self.gen_browser("Firefox", version, platform)
                for version in win_10_ie_versions:
                    self.gen_browser("Internet Explorer", version, platform)
            # mac
            elif platform == "Mac OSX 10.12":
                for version in mac_10_12_chrome_versions:
                    self.gen_browser("Chrome", version, platform)
                for version in mac_10_12_ff_versions:
                    self.gen_browser("Firefox", version, platform)
                for version in mac_10_12_safari_versions:
                    self.gen_browser("Safari", version, platform)

        for i, browser in enumerate(browsers):
            thread = Thread(target=self.get_browser_and_wait, args=[browser])
            self.threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()

        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()

        print ("\n\tAll browsers are setup and ready\n")

        for i, browser in enumerate(browsers_waiting):
            self.tearDown(browser) # I know this doesn't work, it's the approach I would like. tearDown doesn't allow another argument

    def get_browser_driver(self, caps):
        return webdriver.Remote(
                desired_capabilities=caps,
                command_executor="http://%s:%s@hub.crossbrowsertesting.com:80/wd/hub" % (API_EMAIL, API_AUTH)
            )

    def gen_browser(self, browser, version, platform):
        for resolution in desktop_screen_resolution:
            caps = {}
            caps['platform'] = platform
            caps['browserName'] = browser
            caps['version'] = version
            caps['screenResolution'] = resolution
            caps['name'] = 'Login Form Example'
            caps['build'] = '1.0'
            caps['record_video'] = 'false'
            caps['record_network'] = 'false'

            print ("Browser %s %s is now set up for %s at %s\n" % (browser, version, platform, resolution))

            self.browsers.append(caps)

    def get_browser_and_wait(self, browser_data):
        print ("Starting %s %s for %s at %s\n" % (browser_data["browserName"], browser_data["version"], browser_data["platform"], browser_data["screenResolution"]))
        driver = self.get_browser_driver(browser_data)
        browsers_waiting.append({"data": browser_data, "driver": driver})
        print ("%s %s at %s for %s is ready\n" % (browser_data["browserName"], browser_data["version"], browser_data["screenResolution"], browser_data["platform"]))

        while len(self.browsers_waiting) < len(self.browsers):
            print ("Working on %s for %s.... please wait" % (browser_data["browserName"], browser_data["platform"]))
            time.sleep(10)

    def tearDown(self):
        # This is where I'm stumpped
        # looping through the browsers_waiting doesnt work either
        if (self.driver != None):
            self.driver.close()
            self.driver.quit()
```

Then here is a `myproject/sites/sitename/test.py` which is basically the main entrypoint script that will call all the tests

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from unittest import TestSuite, TextTestRunner, TestLoader
from example import exampleTest

def suite():
    loader = TestLoader()
    suite = TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromModule(exampleTest))
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    runner.run(suite())
```

Here is the example test I have in the child/site directory at `myproject/sites/sitename/example.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from initializer import Setup
from elements import Element as element

class exampleTest(Setup):

    def test_Header(self):
        for i, browser in enumerate(Setup().browsers_waiting):
            # this does not work
            driver = browser["driver"]
            self.test_result = None

            try:
                driver.get('https://www.somewebsite.com')
                driver.implicitly_wait(20)

                elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element.searchTitle))
                )

                headerText = elem.text
                expectedHeaderText = 'Some Header'

                self.assertEqual(expectedHeaderText, headerText)
                self.test_result = 'pass'

            except AssertionError as e:
                print ("Something went wrong. Error is %s\n" % e)
                self.test_result = 'fail'
                raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible or my approach to setting this up this way is even the best way. Where I'm struggling is being able to call the individual tests once all of the browsers are set up, and/or I can't access the individual driver to each browser. self.driver is no longer available when you shove them all into a browsers array.

FYI: I got much of this idea from CBT here: https://github.com/crossbrowsertesting/selenium-python/blob/master/parallel/multithreaded/parallel.py

Answer (score 0):

I am not a threading nor a python unittest module expert, so awfully sorry if my answer does not help you solve your problem.

Having said, in your example.py module, the method test_Header relies on an instance dict browsers_waiting defined in the inherited class Setup from initializer module. The dict in question gets populated with key, value pairs when method get_browser_and_wait gets executed.

So at this point, if the method get_browser_and_wait was never called, you are looping through a empty dict

```
def test_Header(self):
    for i, browser in enumerate(Setup().browsers_waiting):
        # this does not work
        driver = browser["driver"]
        self.test_result = None
```

Again having said that, I dont know how the unitest module works and this dict should have some values when referenced.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am actually not a pythonist either. I just happen to work on a project that it's written in. I think `get_browser_and_wait` is called in the second for loop in `setUp`. The cloud cross browser testing provider I can see each browser being stood up, just not calling the desired url. So the browsers just sit there doing nothing. Also please understand my example code is extremely stripped down for brevity and security. The real one is 1,000's of lines long. So it's totally possible I missed critical code. I just wanted to give enough for the example.